# RegEx character length limit fails unit test

Tags: java, regex

I'm am not really good with creating complex RegEx.  I copied the following from another source, in order to enforce somewhat of a password limit for an app:

```
// 8 to 20 char, one digit, one letter
public static final String GOOD_PASSWORD_REGEX =
     "(^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\\d]).*$)";
```

Meanwhile, this unit test fails:

```
String tooLongPassword = "asdfghjkl123456789qwe";  // 21 characters
assertFalse(tooLongPassword.matches(ValidationContants.GOOD_PASSWORD_REGEX));
```

This is one of a handful of similar test cases I am running against this RegEx including others with no letter, no digit, etc. and all the rest pass.

Where is the error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version, the lookahead assertion only checks if it can match a string of 8-20 character length at the start of the string. This of course also succeeds in a string of length 21 and above.

So the `$` needs to become part of the lookahead:

```
// 8 to 20 char, one digit, one letter
public static final String GOOD_PASSWORD_REGEX =
    "(^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d).*$)";
```

But why impose a length maximum on a password? Also the `[]` around the `\d` shortcut are unnecessary.

Furthermore, since you only need the regex to validate the password, not actually return it (because the way it's set up now it will return the entire input string), you can shorten the regex to:

```
"^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)"
```